# Play sound on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to play a sound when the cursor hits an image. I tried to use javascript. the `<audio>`-tag is working, when I say `<audio autoplay>` the soundfile is played. See code below.

Plus, I want the sound to be repeated as long as one is hovering.

I used this tutorial:  [Play Sound on :hover](https://css-tricks.com/play-sound-on-hover/)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 
  <div id="div4">
    <img class="bottom" src="dcim/20190202_102432 copy.jpg" />
    <img class="top" src="dcim/20190202_102432.jpg" />
    <audio>
      <source src="div4.mp3"></source>
    </audio>
  </div>
  
<script>
var audio = $("#div4.mp3")[0];
$("div4").mouseenter(function() {
audio.play();
});
</script>
  
</body>
```

Comment: Do you actually have a div1 somewhere?  In my opinion, you should name your HTML elements much better than div1, div4, etc.

Comment: I do. it's a small file so div1, div4 is enough. But I will make it better next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working code:

1. add id/class to `<audio>` and select the DOM in script as `var audio = $("#audio")[0];`
2. Use  `<source src="..."/>`  and NOT `<source src="..."></source>`
3. Check if your `src` works

```js
var audio = $("#audio")[0];
$("#div4").mouseenter(function() {
audio.play();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div4">
    <img class="bottom" src="dcim/20190202_102432 copy.jpg" />
    <img class="top" src="dcim/20190202_102432.jpg" />
    <audio id="audio">
      <source src="https://css-tricks.com/examples/SoundOnHover/audio/beep.ogg"/>
    </audio>
  </div>
```

**EDIT to your comment**

> 1) I want the sound to be repeated as long as one is hovering;
>
> 2) I want the sound to stop, when the mouse leaves the image

```js
    var audio = $("#audio")[0];
    $("#div4").mouseenter(function() {
    audio.play();
     audio.loop = true;
    });
    $("#div4").mouseleave(function() {
    audio.pause();
    });
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="div4">
        <img class="bottom" src="dcim/20190202_102432 copy.jpg" />
        <img class="top" src="dcim/20190202_102432.jpg" />
        <audio id="audio">
          <source src="https://css-tricks.com/examples/SoundOnHover/audio/beep.ogg"/>
        </audio>
 </div>
```

Comment: now it works! thank you! two questions: 1) I want the sound to be repeated as long as one is hovering; 2) I want the sound to stop, when the mouse leaves the image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the div `<div id="div4">`:

```
$("#div4").mouseenter(function() {...});
```

And your audio should be the audio `<audio>`:

```
var audio = $("audio");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach an eventListener to the object that should trigger the playback of the audio like so:

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
              <meta charset="UTF-8">
              <title></title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="div4">
                  <img class="bottom" src="dcim/20190202_1024322.jpg" />
                  <img class="top" src="dcim/20190202_102432.jpg" />
                  <audio id="audio4">
                    <source src="div4.mp3"></source>
                  </audio>
              </div>
              <script>
                var div4 = document.querySelector('#div4') 
                var audio = document.querySelector('#audio4')
                div4.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(){
                  audio.play()
                });
                div4.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
                  audio.pause()
                });
            </script>
            </body>
            </html>
```